# New Zealand Parent Resident Visa 1000 per year Quota selection criteria?

Tags: new-zealand

I have been exploring New Zealand residence visa options for me and my parents. I have tried but am unable to ascertain the following:

The New Zealand Parent Residence visa (which allows indefinite stay for parents of NZ Citizens/residents, but with travel conditions) is subject to a quota of [1000 each year.](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/parent-resident-visa)

Now is this a random lottery? I can't find how they decide which applicant to choose. Does anyone know anything about this, that is their selection criteria for the 1000 per year quota?

EDIT: Also, I wanted to know whether Parents can be sponsored by just Permanent residents of New Zealand or are Skilled work resident visa holders also eligible?
Asking because they write on the website that [the sponsoring adult child "must be a New Zealand citizen or resident".](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/criteria/parent-resident-visa?nationality=nationality-IND&country=residence-IND) Is this simply any resident or necessarily a **permanent** resident?
Thank you

Comment: This isn't public information anywhere, but if you confirm that personal experience is valid then I can answer your questions - 1. the quote is not a lottery, its first come first served.  You submit an Expression of Interest, and then you are invited to apply - if the quote is met before you are invited to apply, you dont get an invite, and if the quota is met before your application is approved, your application is paused until the next year.  2. Any resident visa class is allowed to be a sponsor.  Be aware that this visa is currently suspended.

Comment: You would be better asking this over on the Travel Stack Exchange btw.

Comment: Immigration is off-topic on Travel SE @Moo.

Comment: @Nij ok, then Expats

Comment: @Moo Thanks for sharing your experience. And yes, I am aware about the suspension. I think I will get the same answer on Expats as well as this is apparently not public information as you said, so people will only be able to answer what they believe to be true. Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about bureaucratic procedure, not the law or legal process, and should be migrated to Expatriates SE.

Comment: @Nij I understand your point, but disagree. Because administrative procedure affects how such applications are treated by the NZ government, that procedure functionally acts as law vis-a-vis these visa applications. I think this is a reasonable query for this forum.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Thanks for supporting. Sorry for the late reply. Does anyone have any update? Is it as bad as Canada? (In Canada,10 Million parents apply for 20K places)